# SQL query to search

Tags: sql-server, database, select

i am new at sqlserver and i just started learning it , and i have a question .
**i want an SQL query that can bring up all rows that were added in the past 6 months. in table 'users' the date is in field 'joined' but its in UNIX time stamp format

**and i want then like another SQL query the same as above but it also with the results sets the field 'activate' in each row to 'yes'

i tried that code :

```
select * from users where time_of_post is like '07/**/2011'
```

** = anyday but i can`t implement it right .

Thank you a lot for your help in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from users
where datediff(mm, time_of_post, getdate()) <= 6
```

What you want to use is the `DATEDIFF()` function, and get the difference between today's day (`GETDATE()`) and the stored dates (`time_of_post`).  If that is less than or equal to 6 months (as denoted by the first parameter, `mm`) then that should be what you're looking for.

**EDIT**:

If you're looking to use this logic for an `UPDATE`, you'd do something like this:

```
update users
set activation = 'yes'
where datediff(mm, time_of_post, getdate()) <= 6
and activation <> 'yes'
```

Comment: Then the second query should be : insert into user(activation) values ('yes') where (select *
from users
where datediff(mm, time_of_post, getdate()) <= 6) ???

Comment: @R.Vector not really, it sounds like you are looking to just update a user record?  Please see my edit.  Let me know if that's what you want.